# Display numbers from A to B with a modifier

Tags: c++, performance, io, sequence

In C++, is it possible to input a operator (such as "-, +, *, /") using a variable and then using it in a calculation?

Example:

```
cin>>(input operator here)
cout<< i (inputted operator here) b;
```

Currently I've done it via using "switch" which is long and very unfriendly to the eye - I strongly believe there is a way to input operators but I can't figure out how.

Here's the code I made - please fix it in the way I've asked if possible (and explain how you've done it!). Help is *much* appreciated :).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool wantedModifyed=0;
string choice;
char operato;

template<typename T>
T get(const string &prompt)
{
    std::cout<<prompt;
    T ret;
    std::cin>>ret;
    return ret;
}

void modifier()
{
    if (!(choice=="Y" || choice=="y" || choice=="N" || choice=="n"))
    {
        cout<<"Y or N: ";
        cin>>choice;
        modifier();
    }
    if (choice=="Y" || choice=="y")
    {
        wantedModifyed=1;
    }
}
void operatorChecker()
{
    if (!(operato=='+' || operato=='-' || operato=='*' || operato=='/'))
    {
        operato=get<char>("\nEnter your modifier (+,-,*,/): ");
        operatorChecker();
    }
}

int OperatorPlus(int a, int c){return a+c;}

int OperatorMinus(int a, int c){return a-c;}

int OperatorMultiply(int a, int c){return a*c;}

int OperatorDivide(int a, int c){return a/c;}

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=get<int>("\nEnter number A: ");
    b=get<int>("\nEnter number B: ");
    if(a>b) swap(a,b);
    modifier();
    if(wantedModifyed==0)
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
            if(i==b) cout<<i<<". ";
            else cout<<i<<", ";
    else
    {
        get<char>("\nEnter your operator (+,-,*,/): ");
        operatorChecker();
        int modifier=get<int>("\nEnter your modifier: ");
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
        {
            switch(operato)
            {
            case '+':
                cout<<OperatorPlus(i,modifier);
                if(i==b) cout<<".";
                else cout<<", "; break;
            case '-':
                cout<<OperatorMinus(i,modifier);
                if(i==b) cout<<".";
                else cout<<", "; break;
            case '*':
                cout<<OperatorMultiply(i,modifier);
                if(i==b) cout<<".";
                else cout<<", "; break;
            case '/':
                cout<<OperatorDivide(i,modifier);
                if(i==b) cout<<".";
                else cout<<", "; break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to search the internet for "c++ calculator" to see if it is possible.  Remember, you'll need to consider *precedence*.

Comment: BTW, if you convert the character response to all upper case or all lower case before comparison, you can reduce your comparisons by 50%!  See `toupper` and `tolower`.

Comment: You can simplify your program by removing the `template`.  The C++ I/O streams will take care of matching data types for you (it's builtin).

Comment: Recursion is not recommended for prompts or menus.  Use `while` or `do-while`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews are you saying it's impossible to input an operator in any way? I'm familiar with the ultra-basic switch calculators, but I heavily doubt there isn't a method to input an operators using cin... Maybe some library?

Comment: No, I'm saying that functions with few lines should not exist (there are some caveats though).  The compiler may optimize them and paste the content where you call the function.

Comment: Try this:  `char operator; cout << "Enter operator: "; cin >> operator;`.  Less complex than using a `template`.

Comment: If you don't like `switch` for the operators, you can always use `std::map` with function pointers or a table with function pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to input *operators* instead of a character type, you'll need to create an operator type and overload `operator>>`.

```
class Operator
{
  public:
    Operator(const char symbol)
    : operator_char(symbol)
    { ; }
    virtual int evaluate(int a, int b) = 0;
  private:
    const char operator_char;
};

class Multiply_Operator : public Operator
{
  public:
    Multiply_Operator() : Operator('*')
    { ; }
};

// ...
Operator * Create_Operator()
{
  static std::map<char, Operator *> dictionary;
  if (dictionary.empty())
  {
     dictionary['*'] = new Multiply_Operator;
     //...
  }
  char operator_char;
  std::cout << "Enter operator (*, /, +, -): ";
  std::cin >> operator_char;
  Operator * p_operator = dictionary[operator_char];
  return p_operator;
}
```

The above is similar to a *Factory Design* pattern and a bit overkill than using a simple `switch` statement.

**Edit 1:  Simplification**
Let's just have a generic operator:

```
class Operator
{
  public:
    friend std::istream operator>>(std::istream& input, Operator& opr);
  private:
    enum Operation_Type
    {
       OPR_MULTIPLE, OPR_DIVIDE, OPR_ADD, OPR_SUBTRACT
    };
    Operation_type ot;
};
std::istream operator>>(std::istream& input, Operator& opr)
{
  char opr_char;
  input >> opr_char;
  switch (opr_char)
  {
    case '*' : opr.ot = OPR_MULTIPLY; break;
    //...
  }
  return input;
}
```

**Summary**
The fundamental issue, is that you need to *associate* or *map* a character to an operator.  There are many methods to do the association, `switch` is one of them, `std::map` is another.

Comment: So there is **no** simpler way to do this such as a simple variable that lets you cin an operator (+, -, *, /, %) and then using it in a cout, i.e. add it like you'd add a number? It seems really flawed and wastes a lot of time for something that should be done in 2 lines.

Comment: The simplest method is to read in the operator as a character.  You still have to associate the character with functionality:  switch or map or table lookup. You could use an if-else ladder, but those are more ugly than the switch.